# Node 16: npm rejects trusted self-signed certificate

Tags: node.js, ssl, npm

I am trying to use `npm install` behind a proxy that intercepts HTTPS connections with a custom CA certificate. I am using Node 16.

The command always fails with:

```
3023 error code SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
3024 error errno SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
3025 error request to https://registry.npmjs.org/yocto-queue/-/yocto-queue-0.1.0.tgz failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

I have marked the CA certificate as trusted by the system -- `curl -vvv -I https://registry.npmjs.org/yocto-queue/-/yocto-queue-0.1.0.tgz` succeeds without certificate verification errors.

I have also exported `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/path/to/my-ca-cert.crt`. I think this was key with Node 12 but does not appear to work anymore.

I have also tried passing `--use-openssl-ca` but observe no change.

I do not want to disable *all* certificate validation, I just want `npm` to trust my CA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked to have `npm` trust the certificates that the system trusts.

```
export npm_config_cafile=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```